# Primordial black hole double-slit thought experiment

Tags: quantum-mechanics, black-holes, double-slit-experiment

Imagine the double-slit experiment where the particles emitted were black holes the mass-energy equivalent of sub-atomoic particles. Would they form an interference pattern?

Comment: I think this would require a working model of quantum gravity to answer.

Comment: Plus what would the slits be made of ? This link might interest readers https://cms.cern/news/search-microscopic-black-hole-signatures-large-hadron-collider

Comment: exactly - so why negative 1?

Comment: thought experiment - perhaps cosmic strings

Comment: also apparently this question has already been addressed and it was awarded a score of 20 - my bad

Answer (score 0):

So one of the issues is "what is a sub-atomic black hole?". At the extreme it is a black hole with a planck-length event-horizon diameter. The slits would occur if three additional black holes were arranged linearly such that there is a small distance between the event horizon of the central black hole and the two adjacent black holes - one on the left, one on the right. The space between would be perhaps 2 planck-lengths.

The detecting structure measures the planck-length event-horizon black holes as gravitional disturbances. The resulting pattern will or will not show an interference pattern. I claim this experiment would show an interference pattern since quantum mechanics demands it - otherwise quantum mechanics does not apply to all sub-atomic phenomena.